# stopping a running akka streams graph willfully

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe, akka-stream, reactive-streams

Suppose I have following simple graph.

```
class KafkaSource[A](kI: KafkaIterator) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[A]] {

  val out = Outlet[A]("KafkaSource.out")

  override val shape = SourceShape.of(out)

  override def createLogic(attr: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          push(out, kI.next)
        }
      })
    }
}

val g = GraphDSL.create(){ implicit b =>
  val source = b.add(new KafkaSource[Message](itr))
  val sink = b.add(Sink.foreach[Message](println))

  source ~> sink
  ClosedShape
}
```

we're running it as

```
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(g).run()
```

I wish to signal the kafkaSource to stop(or artificially complete) instead of pushing the next available element, so that connected stages downstream also stop.

**how do I accomplish that ?**

The scenario being, we have millions of messages in kafka & we would like to stop processing messages everyday at 9pm (for instance) and assuming we're stopping our running applications with a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not relevant for phantomastray any more but helpful for others:

> A KillSwitch allows the completion of graphs of FlowShape from the
>   outside. It consists of a flow element that can be linked to a graph
>   of FlowShape needing completion control. The KillSwitch trait allows
>   to complete or fail the graph(s). [Source: [Akka Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#controlling-graph-completion-with-killswitch)]